# Agile toolkit atk4 php set field value based on anther field value without submitting the form

Tags: php, field, agile, atk4, agiletoolkit

```
I am using agile toolkit code for developing an application , i do have dropdown that get values from database, I want to show selected value from field 1 to field 2 without submit any thing.
```

$form->addField('field1', ['caption' => 'Field 1', 'DropDown', 'values'=> $arra1,'isMultiple' => true ,'readonly' => false, ['dropdownOptions' => ['fullTextSearch' => true]]]);

$form->addField('field2', ['caption' => 'Select Specfic Values', 'DropDown','model' => new view_values($db),'dependency' => function (view_values $model, $data)
{isset($data['field1']) ? $model->addCondition($model->fieldName()->id, 'like', '%' . $data['field1'] . '%') : null;}
,'isMultiple' => true ,'readonly' => false, ['dropdownOptions' => ['fullTextSearch' => true]]]);

issue is Fatal Error atk4\ui\Exception: Unable to add form field (), object: atk4\ui\FormField\DropDown () property: "dependency" value: {}.  Looking for Help. maybe my logic is wrong.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi , Thanks guys for your reply , well I am using Agile toolkit to develop application and I am looking for working example of cascading two dropdown fields value if that make sense , any idea on how it's DONE !

Comment: I have used example in here https://ui.agiletoolkit.org/demos/form-control/lookup-dep.php , but i am having different issues with ('dependency' => ) as the form dosn't want build the addfield ! so I am looking for a better easier example that i can have 2 filed dropdown and once the first filed select the secound fild show selectd value from the model !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I have managed to find a solution for 2 field multi selection scenario:

$values = new view_table($db);
$values->addCondition($db->dsql()->orExpr()->where($db->dsql()->
andExpr()->where('field_status','<>','1')));

$Array = array();
reset($Array);
foreach($values as $row){

$Array[$row['id']] = $row['field_1'].": ".$row['field_2'];

}

$fieldvalue_1 = $form->addField('fieldvalue_1', ['caption' => 'fieldvalue_1', 'DropDown', 'values'=> $Array,'isMultiple' => true ,'readonly' => $readonly, ['dropdownOptions' => ['fullTextSearch' => true]]]);

$fieldvalue_2 = $form->addField('fieldvalue_2', ['caption' => 'fieldvalue_2', 'DropDown', 'values'=> $Array,'isMultiple' => true ,'readonly' => $readonly, ['dropdownOptions' => ['fullTextSearch' => true]]])->set($_GET['val'] ?? 'No value');
$fieldvalue_1->js('change' ,new \atk4\ui\JsReload($fieldvalue_2,['val' => $fieldvalue_1->jsInput()->val()]));
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.